# Import-AzurePublishSettingsFile : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'path'

Tags: azure, azure-powershell

I'm newbie in using the `Azure PowerShell`, and I'm trying to import the `AzurePublishSettingsFile` using this command:

```
Import-AzurePublishSettingsFile C:\Users\Kulasangar G\Downloads\<SubscriptionName>-credentials.publishsettings
```

I'm following [these](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/install-configure-powershell/#use-the-certificate-method) steps to configure the power shell where i found this error when i tried to execute the above command:

`Import-AzurePublishSettingsFile : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'G\Downloads\Visual'.`

The whole error has been pasted [here.](http://pastebin.com/8gTEw6RQ)
What could be the issue? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please put the path to your publish settings file in double quotes.

```
Import-AzurePublishSettingsFile "C:\Users\Kulasangar G\Downloads\<SubscriptionName>-credentials.publishsettings"
```

Because you have a space in the path, PowerShell Cmdlet is considering the path as two parameters `C:\Users\Kulasangar` and `G\Downloads\<SubscriptionName>-credentials.publishsettings` and hence the error.